# Does finding a reversal of a regular expression by automata need automata to be a DFA?

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

If I want to find the reversal of a regular expression using an automata, Do I have to transform the automata to DFA if it wasn't ?

Comment: Colleague Vor has demonstrated that inverse (mirror image) of the language of a regular expression can be found by [merely inverting the expression itself](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/48437/4287). So why would you use the automaton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Represent your automata as a directed graph where each edge is labelled as a symbol of the alphabet. Then:

- Reverse all edges.
- Change the former initial state to an non-initial accepting state.
- Add a new initial state $q_0$, and add a transition (edge) $q_0 \overset{\varepsilon}{\to}q$ towards every state (vertex) $q$ that formerly was an accepting state.

This works even if the starting automata is a NFA.