# How to prove that regular languages are closed under reversal, inductively?

Tags: computability, regular-languages, automata

There are some threads that discuss it but I haven't came across an inductive one yet. All of them involve creating a finite automaton which I would like to avoid (as per my professors requests).

Comment: Your professors will be very happy to learn that the recursive solution for the regex reverse is found in several answers. By templatetypedef: [How to show that a "reversed" regular language is regular](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/3262/4287), by Yuval: [Closure under reversal of regular languages: Proof using Automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/54939/4287) and also [How to prove a language is regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/88050/4287) and then by Vor: [How to prove closure property of regular languages using regular expressions?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/48437/4287)

Comment: What do you mean by "reversal"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to easily solve this:

$$(L_1\cup L_2)^r=L_1^r\cup L_2^r$$
$$(L_1\cap L_2)^r=L_1^r\cap L_2^r$$
$$(L_1L_2)^r=L_2^rL_1^r$$
$$(L^*)^r=(L^r)^*$$

You can use these equalities when proving by induction over the number of operators in the regular expression.